# flexDirection not working

Tags: css, reactjs

I tried everything I can. But it doesnt work. I want to use flexbox to make my elements inline, with this code:

```
<div style={{
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }}>
    <div style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
    <div style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
    <div style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
  </div>
```

Everything I do, it only renders by columns. Someone can save my life?

[image]

Comment: You can just read the question twice to get the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `row` instead of `column` if you want them inline:

```
<div 
  style={{
    display: 'flex',
    flexFlow: "row nowrap",
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }}
>
    <div style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
    <div style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
    <div style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
</div>
```

`flex` is a property for children elements.

Comment: Sorry. I copy and paste it wrong (while trying to make it works). I changed for what you said, and keep not working

Comment: @FernandoMaymone ohhh, You (and I) forgot about `display: flex`, see the edit. https://codesandbox.io/s/48w77o7j74

Answer (score 1):

You need `flexDirection: row` to lay it out horizontally.

Comment: I copy and paste it wrong. Just edited the question. It is still rendering at columns, not by rows